# Expected: end of statement error in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to delete rows that meet the specified condition in the code. I'm also getting syntax error. I'm typing this directly into Excel developer window.

```
Sub create()
    Dim ed(1 To 944)
    Dim female(1 To 944)
    Dim edfemale(1 To 944)

    For i = 1 To 944
        ed(i) = Cells(i, 1).Value
        female(i) = Cells(i, 13).Value
        edfemale(i) = Cells(i, 1) * Cells(i, 13)

        If edfemale(i) = 0 Then
            Cells(i,1 to 14) = ""
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: what are you going to do here: `Cells(i,1 to 14) = ""`?

Comment: Range(Cells(i,1),Cells(i,14)).value = ""

Answer (score 0):

I were unable to reproduce the 'Expected: end of statement' error.  I got a syntax error at line :

```
Cells(i, 1 to 14) = ""
```

But :

If you want to delete the entire Row, you should use :

```
Cells(i).EntireRow.Delete xlUp
```

If instead you want to Clear the row content (like I see in your code), you should use :

```
Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 14)).Clear
```